# Iterative Post request in Postman Getting Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: rest, post, postman

Hi Im Getting Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error while running the Post requisition iterative please help me to resolve this

```
[
   {
      "first_name": "{{Name}}"
   }
]
```

Pre-request Script:

```
var names = JSON.parse(pm.environemnt.get("names"));
if(!names){
names = ["aaa","bbb","ccc,"dddd"];
}
var currentName = names.shift();
pm.environment.set("Name",JSON.stringify(currentName));
pm.environment.set("Names",JSON.stringify(names));
```

Test Script:

```
var names = JSON.parse(pm.environemnt.get("names"));
if(names && names.length > 0){
postman.setNextRequest("CollectionReq");
}
else{
postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Environment: No environment selected

Comment: select an environment: https://assets.postman.com/postman-docs/env-dropdown.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in this statement - `JSON.parse(pm.environemnt.get("names"))` it should be `environment`.

This is in the Prerequest and Test scripts.

Comment: Thanks Danny now getting  JSONError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 I have removed JSON.parse and executed its executing but "AAA" value alone getting passed BBB,CCC,DDD not taking as input please help on this.

Comment: You're running this in the Collection Runner right and not just from the main request builder? Have you saved the changes before running?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my test script it worked.

```
var names = pm.environment.get("names");
if(names && names.length>0) {
  console.log(names);
  console.log(names.length);
console.log(names);
console.log(names.length);
for(var i =0; i< names.length;i++){
postman.setNextRequest("NewPostReq");
}
}
else{
postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```